# Why does pandas pd.plotting.autocorrelation_plot(x) result in different values than a usual autocorrelation calculation?

Tags: python, pandas

After playing around with some auto correlations I recognized that the values shown on the plot by pandas auto correlation plotting module mentioned above differ from the values I receive when I calculate them manually with `x.corr(x.shift(lag))` or with `x.autocorr(lag)`.

Does anybody know if `pd.plotting.autocorrelation_plot(x)` uses another calculation method for the auto correlation than the standard approach?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens because there are `NaN` values in the series. This may help

```
pd.plotting.autocorelation_plot(x.dropna())
```

Note, depending on how you want to deal with `NaN`s, this solution may not suit you. Nevertheless, if you want acf plot, you need to get rid of them.